# Mulesoft 4, How to get only the value of a tag from xml file

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

New to Mule4 and have a question.
I am posting a simple xml file using postman

```
<cust>
  <act>1234</act>
</cust>
```

In my flow I have 
Listener->TransformMessage->logger 
Inside TransformMessage I have the following:
Added a new target called f1 as variable

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var myXML = payload
---
{
    f1: myXML.cust.act
}
```

And in the logger I am printing the value  using #[vars.f1] and the output I am getting is {f1=1234} which is right.
So my question is how can I only get the value “1234” out of it? Reason is let says I want to use this in a query, for example

Select name, address from account where accountNumber = ':vars.f1' 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are wrapping the result in an object with a field `f1`

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var myXML = payload
---
{
    f1: myXML.cust.act
}
```

So what you should do is just return the value like

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
var myXML = payload
---
myXML.cust.act
```

Comment: Thank you. Well that works if I add #[payload.cust.act] in the logger. Then I get 1234. However how can I add that to a variable ?

Comment: You can use the `set-variable `

Comment: even set-variable not working. it seems f1 IS based on key/value. is there a way to assign the value of that key to a variable?